# RTF to Plain-Text?

Tags: t-sql

Did you ever get the library from this post? We have a need to convert whole, large, whole tables worth of RTF information into something usable and would rather not reinvent if possible.

[Converting RTF in a text column to plain text in bulk](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17454/converting-rtf-in-a-text-column-to-plain-text-in-bulk)

Comment: This question is about client-side programming and thus should be asked elsewhere, probably on [so]. Or were you hoping to solve this on the server side?

Comment: This question is not really a question, but rather a comment about a different post. Unfortunately the OP doesn't have the reputation to comment on the other post, and sadly this exposes a hole in the current model: their options are to hold their tongue or post a comment in the form of an answer, which I could then convert to a comment on their behalf. Which makes the 50 reputation requirement kind of funny...

Answer (score 1):

Probably can't/don't want to do this in the database.

You can use Apache Tika to convert RTF to plain text: http://tika.apache.org/1.4/formats.html#Rich_Text_Format

Tika internally uses javax.swing.text.rtf for this.